# Dialog with results

Tags: java, dictionary, javafx, dialog, alignment

I have a map with data of a "benchmark" for my little algorithm.
Keys represent the name of the benchmark, values the time needed.
I want to create a Dialog with lists those results in an easy to read way.
This is what I got so far:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
    Dialog<Object> dialog = new Dialog<>();
    dialog.setTitle("Result");
    DialogPane pane = dialog.getDialogPane();
    VBox list = new VBox();
    for (Entry<String, Long> entry : resultMap.entrySet()) {
        BorderPane box = new BorderPane();
        box.setLeft(new Text(entry.getKey() + ": "));
        box.setRight(new Text(entry.getValue().toString() + "ms"));
        list.getChildren().add(box);
    }
    list.getChildren().add(new Text("Check: " + (logic.getResult() ? "PASSED" : "FAILED")));
    pane.getChildren().add(list);
    //pane.setPrefSize(pane.getPrefWidth(), 200); needed otherwhise the dialog is cut off
    dialog.show();
});
```

There are multiple problems with this.

- This Dialog isn't closeable for whatever reason.
- The "Time" result is
  aligned left instead of right.

It works for me inside scene builder, but since I need to generate those dynamically that's no possible choice.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rules about closing a dialog are described in the [`Dialog` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html) under "Dialog Closing Rules". In short, you need to add a button of some kind, which you can do with

```
pane.getButtonTypes().add(ButtonType.OK);
```

The reason the layout of `list` is not working correctly is that you use

```
pane.getChildren().add(list);
```

The dialog pane has a specific structure (again, see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/DialogPane.html)), and if you "blindly" add a node to the list of children, the dialog pane doesn't know how to manage it. Use `setContent(...)` instead:

```
// pane.getChildren().add(list);
pane.setContent(list);
```

This will also avoid the need to set the preferred size of the dialog pane.